# Is it likely somebody stole My filler cap?

Tags: oil

Civic vti 2000 coupe.

Topped I engine oil up then went for a drive 10 miles, break then did return journey and left car parked up for a week.

When I came back I found the bonnet was open(not fully just a little like when u open with latch) not fully open and I found the engine oil filler cap was missing.

I first wondered if I had forgot to put the cap back on and close the bonnet after the oil change however I doubt that because as mentioned I went for a drive after the change, yet the bonnet didnt shoot up while driving.  Also you would have expected the oil to shoot out but the dipstick was on normal which is where i toppers it up to.  I don’t see why someone would steal it it’s unlikely someone has a similar car around. Also it’s on low suspension
Can’t get your head under to open the latch.

Anyway based on my description does it sound like someone stole it or could this be down to me forgetting to put the cap on and close the bonnet - very unlikely I would make two mistakes no?

Strange.  I’m wondering if theft is the best explanation here? Surely if I had forgot the oil would have come out during driving?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn’t the alarm have sounded if someone opened the bonnet?

Comment: Whatever happened - go buy another. Bonnets can be opened - when the cable breaks for example.

Comment: The bonnet didn't shoot up because the catch, even while not fully closed, will hold the bonnet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest explanation is usually the most accurate.

You probably left the cap off and also didn't firmly close the hood.  Some cars don't spew oil out the filler hole while others do.

Comment: And the cap rattled around and fell out the engine bay.